# Remaining connected to database when running php through form action

Tags: php, mysql, forms, function, action

I'm using dropzone.js to run my image uploader, and medoo to run my database queries. The idea is to have a randomly generated string associated with an image. Then resize the image to various sizes and upload them all where I could then call all the images via a 50x50, 100x100, etc. tag associated with the randomized string. Additionally a long string in the table 'photos' where I can then explode() into a list of all associated images (e5tg,23rfg,5rgf into an array) for that particular product. All that works fine and dandy, until I try to connect to the database once the imageuploader.php is loaded. I'm also not sure the function generateRandomString() is passing to the imageuploader.php file either. I'm sure this is probably a relatively simple fix, but I just can't seem to get my head wrapped around it. Here's my code.

First the form:

```
require_once 'medoo.php';
//Connect to DB
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "main");
if (!$link) {
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
}

//DB query string
$database = new medoo([
'database_type' => 'mysql',
'database_name' => 'main',
'server' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'charset' => 'utf8'
]);
<link href="css/dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
<form action="include/imageuploader.php?oid=1" class="dropzone"></form>
```

imageuploader.php

```
<?php

$photos = $database->get("orders", ["photos"],["oid" => $_GET['oid']]);
$rng = generateRandomString();
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1
$storeFolder = '../uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $rng . "-full.jpg";  //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFile);
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($targetFile);

$newwidth=350;
$newheight=350;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

$newwidth1=200;
$newheight1=200;
$tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);

$newwidth2=100;
$newheight2=100;
$tmp2=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth2,$newheight2);

$newwidth3=50;
$newheight3=50;
$tmp3=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth3,$newheight3);

imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($tmp2,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth2,$newheight2,$width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($tmp3,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth3,$newheight3,$width,$height);


$filename = "../uploads/" . $rng . "-350x350.jpg";
$filename1 = "../uploads/" . $rng . "-200x200.jpg";
$filename2 = "../uploads/" . $rng . "-100x100.jpg";
$filename3 = "../uploads/" . $rng . "-50x50.jpg";

imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);
imagejpeg($tmp2,$filename2,100);
imagejpeg($tmp3,$filename3,100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp1);
imagedestroy($tmp2);
imagedestroy($tmp3);
}

$new_photos = $photos['photos'] . "," . $rng;
$database->update("orders",["photos"=> $new_photos],["oid" => $_GET['oid']]);

?>
```

Does one simply not connect to your database once you load PHP through a form action?

Comment: Where is your database connection code...?

Comment: This is all a series of include files nested into one another.. I updated the post to show the include on the main index

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `$database` in `imageuploader.php` you will have to include the file where you fill that variable (in your case the form PHP file, which is stupid).
You should write one simple PHP script which does nothing else but either open the database connection or make sure the connection is still open. Then you can simply include that file wherever you need to deal with the database.